# Powershell: Is there a safer way to quit a program than Stop-Process

Tags: powershell, crash

Usually when I want to close a crashed application, I employ a two-step approach. Say, for instance, I want to quit RStudio, I would do this

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\> Get-Process rstudio

Handles NPM(K)  PM(K)     WS(K)  VM(K)  CPU(s)    Id ProcessName
    210    89  158144    133840   570    2.67   4508 rstudio

PS C:\Users\Admin\> Stop-Process 4508
```

This effectively kills the program.

My concern is this: What if someone types in the wrong `Id` by mistake and the value provided happens to coincide with some other process leading to serious damage? Is there a safety net one can apply to prevent this?

Comment: `Get-Process "rstudio" | Stop-Process`? That would stop _all_ rstudio threads and only those. No need to play with pids

Comment: Okay will try that out next session. But I don't understand how this would work since `Get-Process` returns more than just the `Id`.

Comment: Stop-Process is using the object passed to it and binding on properties both cmdlets share. about_pipeline would be a help topic to start with. Practice with `notepad`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stop-Process` is fairly low-level and straightforward, but, like many PowerShell cmdlets, you can specify the `Confirm` common parameter to give you a bit of a safety net:

```
PS C:\Users\example> Stop-Process -Confirm 11644

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Stop-Process" on target "notepad (11644)".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

The example above kills a notepad.exe process by its PID, but by adding `-Confirm`, PowerShell will prompt you before killing the process *and show you the process name* so you can verify that it is indeed the process you want to terminate.

Comment: Thanks. I will henceforth use that parameter!